# How to insert data into a certain row?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

basically, I used a query to move the data (userid to QTY) from another table (cart) to this table shown below (cart2). After that, i will then insert two sets of data invoice_id and date into the database based on the ord_id.

Below is my database:

[image: My Database]

From the image, I've tried inserting the data and only the 1st row worked. Subsequent row does not get the subsequent data i inserted.

Here is the code:

```
$user= $_SESSION['id'];
$trx_id = $_GET['tx'];
$date = date("Y-m-d") ;
```

Move data from cart to cart2

```
$move_cart = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO cart2(userid,Product_ID,Product_name,Price,QTY)
    SELECT userid,Product_ID,Product_name,Price,QTY FROM cart WHERE userid=?");
$move_cart->bind_param("s",$user);
```

If it succeeded, delete data from cart

```
if ($move_cart->execute()) {
    $delete_cart =$db->prepare("delete from cart where userid =?");
    $delete_cart->bind_param("s", $user);
    $delete_cart->execute();
}
```

*>     insert data(trx_id and date) to cart 2 based on ord_id*

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM cart2 ";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$ord = $row['ord_id'];
$update_cart = $db->prepare("UPDATE cart2 SET invoice_id =?,date =? WHERE ord_id =?");
$update_cart->bind_param("ssi",$trx_id,$date,$ord);
$update_cart->execute();
$ord ++;
```

The error is probably in the last piece of code. other codes are just for referencing.

Comment: You are doing an `UPDATE`, not an `INSERT` in your last piece of code.  Was this intentional?  `UPDATE` will only modify _existing_ records; it won't add new ones.

Comment: Yes. If I use `INSERT`, it will create a new row with only invoice_id and date like [this](http://imgur.com/iMSyA2t)